# Combinations from picking r from 2n objects (1...2n), repetitions allowed, if odd object appears, even object must appear?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I am very stuck on this question with combinations. This is where I am at in the problem:
Two cases:
**picking an even object:**
pick *r* from *n* numbered (2, 4, 6 ... 2*n*)

**picking an odd object in which an even object must appear:**
I do not know how to approach this point.

Since the two cases are disjoint, we can add them.

I am not sure if I am going in the right direction, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How many combinations are not valid (containing only odd-numbered objects)? Subtract this from the total number of combinations.

Comment: Suppose that you pick $2$, then $2$, then $4$; does this count as a different selection from $2$, then $4$, then $2$, or do they count as the same selection? In other words, does the order of selection matter, or just the specific objects and their multiplicities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome !

The problem can be easily solved by first counting all possible combinations with repetitions, and subtracting those that consist **entirely** of odd numbers, thus

${2n+r-1\choose r} - {n+r-1\choose r}$